# How to remove a third party selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I imported a third party CSS (which I'm not allowed to modify) into my application. This CSS file is declaring a class name and a selector, e.g.:

```
.third-party-class{
  color: blue;
}

.third-party-class:last-of-type{
  color: red;
}
```

My goal is to remove the `.third-party-class:last-of-type` selector completely by using CSS only. Of course you could just override the `.third-party-class:last-of-type` selector and copy every property from `.third-party-class`. But this is really inconvenient if `.third-party-class` has a lot of properties.

```css
.third-party-class{
  color: blue;
}

.third-party-class:last-of-type{
  color: red;
}

.desired-li{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
Currently:
  <ul>
    <li class="third-party-class">one</li>
    <li class="third-party-class">two</li>
    <li class="third-party-class">three</li>
</ul>

Desired:
  <ul>
    <li class="desired-li">one</li>
    <li class="desired-li">two</li>
    <li class="desired-li">three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Question**

Is it possible to override/remove a CSS selector completely, without redeclaring all properties of the "base" class by using CSS (no JS) only?

Comment: No, once the stylesheet has been loaded, the only way to override its styles is to re-declare them. That's kind of the whole point of **cascading** stylesheets ;)

Comment: Use `!important` to override what you need

Comment: I might have understood the problem wrong but doesnt `all: initial;` answer your question?

Comment: @SilverSurfer please don't recommend the use of `!important`!

Comment: @silversurfer this post it not about how to override a class.. it's about "ignoring" a selector without re-declaring every property

Comment: @AmmoPT your suggestion didn't work for me. `initial` is not setting the properties that are declared in `third-party-class`. I used following class: `.third-party-class:last-of-type{
  all: initial;
}` which is removing every css property from the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are dealing with `last-of-type` and you cannot change the CSS, you can add an extra element that will trigger this selector and hide it (I suppose you are able to adjust the HTML):

```css
.third-party-class {
  color: blue;
}

.third-party-class:last-of-type {
  color: red;
  background:pink;
  font-size:250px;
  opacity:0.9;
  display:flex;
  vertical-align:sub;
  /*doesn't matter what CSS you will have here*/
}

ul li:last-of-type {
  display:none!important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="third-party-class">one</li>
  <li class="third-party-class">two</li>
  <li class="third-party-class">three</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that BenM made to your original question.

But...If the CSS is as simple (only one line) as your fiddle leads me to believe you could just use "!important" on the selector you want to overwrite.

```
.third-party-class:last-of-type{
    color: blue !important;
 }
```

That would allow you, on a selector by selector basis (assuming there are more than just color being used), specify what you want the third party code to do.

Comment: as stated in my question `without redeclaring all properties of the "base" class`, which means without redeclaring `color: blue`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `[attribute^=value]` Selector, it will overide every ellement who starts with "value" so you can make something like this:

```css
.third-party-class{
  background: blue;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.third-party-class:last-of-type{
  background: red;
}


div[class^="third-party-class"]{
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
<div class="third-party-class"></div>
```

*Sorry if i do not understand it right*

Comment: simply selecting class will be enough, why complicating with attribute selector?